# Appending a random number at the end of every row in a file using Python

Tags: python

I have a file say, `file.txt`, which looks like:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,4,3,6
```

Now I want to add an extra column with every row of that file which will be any random number between `0.51 to 0.99`

I am trying the below code:

```
import random
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input:
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in input:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + random.uniform(0.51, 0.99)
            print(line, file=output)
```

But here I am getting an error saying :

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you cannot add a string and a float - you need to convert the float to a string first, like this:

```py
line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + str(random.uniform(0.51, 0.99))
```

or if you want to use an f-string to format it you can do it a couple ways

```py
line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + f"{random.uniform(0.51, 0.99):.2f}"
```

```py
line = f"{line.rstrip('\n')},{random.uniform(0.51, 0.99):.2f}"
```

Comment: Here if I want to make sure my random number has 2 places after the decimal point then what should I do? Because I am getting a random number say, `0.6001140403853109` but all I want is `0.60`

Comment: You can use `:.2f` in the f string (edited the answer) or use `("%.2f" % myfloat)`

Answer (score 1):

change `line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + random.uniform(0.51, 0.99)` to `line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + str(random.uniform(0.51, 0.99))`

Comment: Here if I want to make sure my random number has 2 places after the decimal point then what should I do? Because I am getting a random number say, 0.6001140403853109 but all I want is 0.60

Answer (score 1):

Use a format string or wrap the random number in a str object